# How can I solve this Char matrix problem in C?

Tags: c, matrix

There are given a word, a number n, and a matrix of n by n characters. I have to found the spots where the word is located in the matrix and output the coordinates of the starting point. The word can be found reading from right to left, from left to right, from up to down or from down going up, so 4 directions.

eg:

```
    mere
    5
    erema
    hereb
    bmere
    bamer
    aemre   ---> output: 0 3 (right->left)
                         0 3 (up->down)
                         2 1 (left->right)
                         3 2 (down ->up)
```

Here's the code I wrote in main() but it doesn't show the right thing.

```
int n, c, x, y, z, x1, t, x2, r, x3; char s[101];
fgets(s, 101, stdin);
printf("n="); scanf_s("%d", &n);
char a[90][90];
for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        c = getchar();
        a[i][j] = c;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (a[i][j] == s[0])
        {
            x = 0; x1 = 0; x2 = 0; x3 = 0; y = j - 1; z = j + 1; t = i + 1, r = i - 1;
            for (int k = 1; k < strlen(s); k++) {
                if (s[k] == a[i][y])
                {
                    x++; y--;
                }
            }
            if (x == strlen(s) - 1) printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
            for (int k = 1; k < strlen(s); k++)
            {
                if (s[k] == a[i][z])
                {
                    x1++; z++;
                }
            }
            if (x1 == strlen(s) - 1) printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
            for (int k = 1; k < strlen(s); k++)
            {
                if (s[k] == a[t][j])
                {
                    x2++; t++;
                }
            }
            if (x2 == strlen(s) - 1) printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
            for (int k = 1; k < strlen(s); k++)
            {
                if (s[k] == a[r][j])
                {
                    x3++; r--;
                }
            }
            if (x3 == strlen(s) - 1) printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the first time you call `c = getchar();` it will read the newline. Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer). And if you enter data in the nested loops line by line, then each line ends also in newline which is always read by `getchar()` and ditto if you enter the data with each character individually followed by newline. It's just another character to `getchar()`.

Comment: Ok, but I still can't see what's the problem with my code

Comment: Have you dealt with the newline characters yet?

Comment: How can I actually do that on my code? I tried to get rid of the new line after scanf_s by adding a getchar() after but still doesn't work.

Comment: By ignoring every input to `getchar()` that is a newline. So where you have `c = getchar();` change that to `while((c = getchar()) == '\n') {}`

Comment: Ok, done that; now I can input 10 lines so double and shows nothing

Comment: I think you should employ the debugging tool to analyse exactly what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Another `getchar()` after `s_scanf()` just to consume the `'\n'` character should do it.

```
printf("n="); scanf_s("%d", &n);
getchar();
```

This will only work if you want to get rid of the `'\n'` character left by `scanf()`.